# Ralink RT3290 wifi/bluetooth driver not working

Tags: 14.04, wireless, ralink

I ran this command `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`
and it says `Hard blocked: yes`

Anyway I am not able to get wifi on at all. I just switched from Windows to Ubuntu.

[image]

Comment: 14.04 is quite old. You might have better luck with 18.04.

Comment: i have installed latest ubuntu version only 18.04

Answer (score 0):

Two possible problems here:

- RFkill blocks device.

  Note the `Hard blocked: yes` line in your output above.
  You can try to switch it `on` with `sudo rfkill unblock all`.
  Also make sure that you have turned on Wi-Fi hardware switch on the laptop itself.
- Old driver issue. I do not believe in that as Ralink drivers are stable.

  You can stay on 14.04 LTS but use newer kernel on it. While using Ethernet connection, install the 4.4 kernel from 16.04 LTS with `sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-xenial`.